# Failed to load plugin '@next/next' when running npm run lint in GitLab CI

Tags: next.js, eslint

Locally I can run `npm run lint` without issues on Windows. However, on my ubuntu gitlab runner I get followint error:

```
Failed to load plugin '@next/next' declared in '.eslintrc.json » eslint-config-next/core-web-vitals » /home/gitlab-runner/builds/iPXPkofu/0/isi/micat/front_end/node_modules/eslint-config-next/index.js': Unexpected token '.'
Referenced from: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/iPXPkofu/0/isi/micat/front_end/node_modules/eslint-config-next/index.js
```

The .eslintrc.json file is auto-generated and only contains:

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```

I also tried with "extends": "next".

=> Is this a bug of next.js? If not, what can I do?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "micat",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "5.1.3",
    "crossfilter2": "1.5.4",
    "d3": "7.5.0",
    "dc": "4.2.7",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "next": "12.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "24.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "28.1.2",
    "jest-cli": "27.2.0",
    "jest-jasmine2": "27.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accorrding to
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38220
its due to different versions of nodejs

- I installed nvm and updated nodejs from version 12.22 to to version 18.6.0 then deployed it for the other users (gitlab-runner)

  n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local

Also see
https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-nvm-on-ubuntu-20-04/
https://dzone.com/articles/making-nodejs-available-to-all-users-with-nvm

- I removed the node_modules folder with `rm -r node_modules` an reinstalled with `npm install`

=> `npm run lint` works now